# Is there any word or phrase for the idea that "everything in the universe is a miracle"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, concept

Is there any word or phrase for the idea that "everything in the universe (including the creatures) is a miracle"? Or someone who chooses to see everything as a miracle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From a philosophical point of view, I believe you could call this **[pantheism](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/pantheism/)**: the belief that all things are part of god.  However, the answer depends on how we understand the word 'miracle'.

Comment: Yes. By some definitions of the word, *everything* being a miracle would be a logical impossibility. In fact, *most* things being a miracle wouldn't make sense either.